# Entry into France

Tags: visa, france

I have obtained a French work visa (type D) with a start date of 1 June 2022 but I have already entered Europe via Finland in the middle of May, using my Australian passport which allows me to be here without a visa for up to three months.

When I switch to my French visa on 1 June 2022, am I allowed to enter France from another Schengen country or do I have to leave the Schengen area at the end of May and enter France officially from outside the Schengen on 1 June 2022?

Comment: If you do leave the Schengen area, you don't have to re-enter directly in France.  I suspect that you don't need to leave and re-enter, but I doubt that you'll find a clear statement about it one way or the other.  Are you going to have to apply for a _carte de séjour?_

Answer (score 2):

The main constraint is that in many cases, you will have some formalities to complete within two or three months of entering France (exact details depend on the type of visa). The date of entry is easiest to prove if you land directly in France and get a stamp in your passport but it is not formally a requirement. Entering through another country is definitely allowed.

In general, I would recommend keeping some documentation of your trip to Finland and the date of your entry in France (like a boarding pass) although in this case it is very unlikely to have any consequences as you have only been in the Schengen area for two weeks. Simply apply for the visa validation or residence permit (if you need either of these) sooner rather than later and do not wait to get close to the deadline.